# xlwings on mac os using api.autofill() dont work

Tags: python, autofill, xlwings

I know the code below is for Windows but is there somebody who can tell me how it works for Mac OS?

```
import xlwings as xw
from xlwings.constants import AutoFillType

wb = xw.Book('Book1')
sheet = wb.sheets(1)
sheet.range('A2').api.AutoFill(sheet.range("A2:A10").api,
                               AutoFillType.xlFillDefault)
```

Answer (score 1):

problem solved!

```
import xlwings as xw
from xlwings.constants import AutoFillType

wb = xw.Book('euromillions.csv')
ws = wb.sheets('euromillions')

ws.range("A2").api.autofill(destination = ws.range("A2:A5").api, type = AutoFillType.xlFillDefault)
```